# How can I Get my Button to stop sending Error [INTERACTION_ALREADY_REPLIED]?

Tags: javascript, node.js, button, discord.js, bots

I made what will be the start of my button-based RPG bot the goal was to get the menu no matter what button I pressed to roll a d20 I was going to work on functions for each button later first the buttons are working great then I start getting errors. I used the following code to produce the action row:

```js
//Remember to run " node deploy-commands.js " to register your commands!

const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('@discordjs/builders');
const { MessageActionRow, MessageButton, MessageEmbed  } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('menu')
        .setDescription('Brings up the Main Menu'),
    async execute(interaction, client) {
        const row = new MessageActionRow()
                        .addComponents(
                                
                        
                                new MessageButton()
                                        .setCustomId('dice-button')
                                        .setLabel('Dice bag')
                                        .setStyle("DANGER"),

                                new MessageButton()
                                        .setCustomId('spells-button')
                                        .setLabel('Spells')
                                        .setStyle("PRIMARY"),
                                        
                                new MessageButton()
                                        .setCustomId('inventory-button')
                                        .setLabel('Inventory')
                                        .setStyle("SUCCESS"),
                        );
                        await interaction.reply({content: 'Main menu', ephemeral: true, components: [row]})

                        //button handler
                        client.on('interactionCreate', interaction => {
                        if (!interaction.isButton()) return;
                        console.log(interaction);

                        interaction.reply(`${interaction.user} rolled ${Math.round(Math.random() * 20)}`);
                        });
    },
};
```

After a few presses I got the error:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'on')
> at Object.execute (C:\Users\levan\Desktop\Discordbot\Test bots\5 Buttons\commands\Menu.js:33:32)
> at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
> at async Client. (C:\Users\levan\Desktop\Discordbot\Test bots\5 Buttons\index.js:40:3)
> C:\Users\levan\Desktop\Discordbot\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\interfaces\InteractionResponses.js:89
> if (this.deferred || this.replied) throw new Error('INTERACTION_ALREADY_REPLIED');
> ^
>
> Error [INTERACTION_ALREADY_REPLIED]: The reply to this interaction has
> already been sent or deferred.
> at CommandInteraction.reply (C:\Users\levan\Desktop\Discordbot\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\interfaces\InteractionResponses.js:89:46)
> at Client. (C:\Users\levan\Desktop\Discordbot\Test bots\5 Buttons\index.js:43:22)
> at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {   [Symbol(code)]:
> 'INTERACTION_ALREADY_REPLIED'

I've tried to delete and redo the code but this is the closest I've gotten to the code working was with the code above.

I've also seen the following error

> C:\Users\levan\Desktop\Discordbot\Test bots\5 Buttons\index.js:10 await interaction.reply({content: 'Main menu', ephemeral: true,
> components: [row]})                                          ^^^^^
>
> SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level
> bodies of modules
> at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:352:18)
> at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1031:15)
> at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1065:27)
> at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
> at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
> at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
> at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:79:12)
> at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47

After trying to revamp the code above but I'm not sure why I moved the:

```
    await interaction.reply({content: 'Main menu', ephemeral: true, components: [row]})

//button handler
client.on('interactionCreate', interaction => {
if (!interaction.isButton()) return;
console.log(interaction);

interaction.reply(`${interaction.user} rolled ${Math.round(Math.random() * 20)}`);
});
```

Over a to or two in my file to make it easier for me to piece this together in my head and I'm guessing that's what killed it but even when I try to move it back it gives the same error.

the main resource I'm using is https://discordjs.guide/interactions/buttons.html#responding-to-buttons

Comment: Try replacing the second `interaction.reply` with `interaction.editReply()`

Answer (score 1):

**at async Client. (C:\Users\levan\Desktop\Discordbot\Test bots\5 Buttons\index.js:40:3)**

I removed a command that I shouldn't have put in the index.

I tried to remove the await in the menu.js and got:

> TypeError: interaction.Reply is not a function
> at Object.execute (C:\Users\levan\Desktop\Discordbot\Test bots\5 Buttons\commands\Menu.js:32:43)
> at Client. (C:\Users\levan\Desktop\Discordbot\Test bots\5 Buttons\index.js:41:17)
> at Client.emit (node:events:402:35)
> at InteractionCreateAction.handle (C:\Users\levan\Desktop\Discordbot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\InteractionCreate.js:66:12)
> at Object.module.exports [as INTERACTION_CREATE] (C:\Users\levan\Desktop\Discordbot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\INTERACTION_CREATE.js:4:36)
> at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (C:\Users\levan\Desktop\Discordbot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:350:31)
> at WebSocketShard.onPacket (C:\Users\levan\Desktop\Discordbot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:443:22)
> at WebSocketShard.onMessage (C:\Users\levan\Desktop\Discordbot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:300:10)
> at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\levan\Desktop\Discordbot\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:199:18)
> at WebSocket.emit (node:events:390:28)

this allowed the menu to pop but the button was still tossing the error:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'on')
> at Object.execute (C:\Users\levan\Desktop\Discordbot\Test bots\5 Buttons\commands\Menu.js:35:32)
> at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
> at async Client. (C:\Users\levan\Desktop\Discordbot\Test bots\5 Buttons\index.js:41:3)
> C:\Users\levan\Desktop\Discordbot\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\interfaces\InteractionResponses.js:89
> if (this.deferred || this.replied) throw new Error('INTERACTION_ALREADY_REPLIED');
> ^
>
> Error [INTERACTION_ALREADY_REPLIED]: The reply to this interaction has
> already been sent or deferred.
> at CommandInteraction.reply (C:\Users\levan\Desktop\Discordbot\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\interfaces\InteractionResponses.js:89:46)
> at Client. (C:\Users\levan\Desktop\Discordbot\Test bots\5 Buttons\index.js:44:22)
> at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {   [Symbol(code)]:
> 'INTERACTION_ALREADY_REPLIED'

trying to node after that I got the error:

> > C:\Users\levan\Desktop\Discordbot\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\BaseCommandInteraction.js:193
> > InteractionResponses.applyToClass(BaseCommandInteraction,
> > ['deferUpdate', 'update']);
> > ^
>
> TypeError: InteractionResponses.applyToClass is not a function
> at Object. (C:\Users\levan\Desktop\Discordbot\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\BaseCommandInteraction.js:193:22)
> at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
> at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
> at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
> at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
> at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
> at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
> at Object. (C:\Users\levan\Desktop\Discordbot\node_modules\discord.js\src\index.js:74:27)
> at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
> at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)

After looking at the referenced code in the error I came to the following conclusion one of the API's I installed must not be working with my code.

I tore out any code I did not personally make and reloaded the API's one at a time. same error.

turns out the following code shouldn't of been in the command file...

```
 //button handler
client.on('interactionCreate', interaction => {
    if (!interaction.isButton()) return;
    console.log(interaction);

    interaction.reply(`You rolled ${Math.round(Math.random() * 20)}`);
});
```

moved it to the index and the issue when away